# Tightness of inequalities for various matrix norms

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

For a general inequality involving matrix norms, does the choice of the norm influence the tightness of the inequality?

Eg. In $\|AB\| \leq \|A\| \|B\|$,

Does the choice of the norm affect the tightness of the inequality? Is there any particular norm in which inequalities are always tighter than other norms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of a matrix norm where the submultiplicative inequality is **not** tight (except when $A$ or $B$ is zero):

Taking $|\cdot|$ to be any norm (for example, take the spectral norm), we note that the norm $\|\cdot\|$ defined by $\|A\| = c|A|$ is another matrix norm for any $c > 1$.

We note that if $|AB| = |A| \cdot |B|$, then 
$$
\|AB\| = c\cdot|A| \cdot |B| = \frac 1c \cdot \|A\| \cdot \|B\| < \|A\| \cdot \|B\|
$$
So, we can create a matrix norm that is only tight when $A = 0$ or $B = 0$.

---

For most norms (i.e. for any I can think of, though I'm not sure that this is guaranteed), this inequality is tight in the sense that we can choose *some* non-zero matrices $A,B$ such that
$$
\|AB\| = \|A\|\cdot \|B\|
$$
However, here's a result that seems to be at least in the spirit of your question: let $\|\cdot\|$ denote any unitarily invariant norm, and let $|\cdot|$ denote the spectral norm.  We always have $|A| \leq \|A\|$, and moreover,
$$
\|ABC\| \leq |A|\cdot\|B\|\cdot |C|
$$
Among the Schatten $p$-norms, we also have Hölder's inequality, which is to say
$$
\|AB\|_1 \leq \|A\|_p \|A\|_q
$$

Comment: I seem to have a wrong notion of tightness. I now understand that an inequality is tight when it can become an equality. Is there any other notion to express closeness? A notion to express that when there is no equality, how close do the functions on both the sides of the inequality get?

Comment: @jinkx that is what people usually mean when they say tightness.  However, often we want to say a little bit more.

Comment: Yeah. So in my question by _tighter_ I meant that the difference between both sides is always lesser.

Comment: See my latest edit for general tightness

Comment: @jinkx right.  In particular, my inequality
$$
\|AB\| \leq |A| \cdot \|B\|
$$
is *tighter* than the usual $\|AB\| \leq \|A\|\cdot \|B\|$ since $|A| \leq \|A\|$.